# How to chain generically chain functions returning Either with an operator like `andThen`?

Tags: scala

**Problem:** Chaining multiple Either returning functions, the `Left` of which are all failures inheriting from a common sealed trait `InternalError`. However, the compiler complains that the *chain* is returning `Either[_,Success]` instead of `Either[InternalError, Success]`.

Here's the code that does the chaining:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
object EitherExtension {
  implicit class AndThenEither[A,B](val e: Function1[A,Either[_,B]]) {
    //get ability to chain/compose functions that return aligning Eithers
    def andThenE[C](f:Function1[B, Either[_,C]]): Function1[A, Either[_,C]] = {
      (v1: A) => e.apply(v1).flatMap(b => f.apply(b))
    }
  }
}
```

As was pointed out in the comments this discards the type of `Left`. If I change it the below it will not work since the final output can be of type `Either[X|Y, C]` which resolves to `Either[_,C]` and I'm back to square one.

```
implicit class AndThenEither[A,B,X](val e: (A) => Either[X, B]) {
    def andThenE[C,Y](f:(B) => Either[Y, C]): (A) => Either[_, C] = {
      (v1: A) => e.apply(v1).flatMap(b => f.apply(b))
    }
  }
```

Here's the example showing the compositional failure of type alignment:

```
import EitherExtension._
object AndThenComposition {
  //sample type definitions of failure responses
  sealed trait InternalError
  case class Failure1() extends InternalError
  case class Failure2() extends InternalError
  //sample type definitions
  case class Id(id: Int)
  case class Stuff()
  //sample type definitions of successful responses
  case class Output1()
  case class Output2()
  case class InputRequest()

  val function1: (InputRequest) => Either[Failure1, Output1] = ???
  val function2: (Output1)  => Either[Failure2, Output2] = ???

  def doSomething(s:Id, l:List[Stuff]): Either[InternalError, Output2] = {
    val pipeline = function1 andThenE function2
    pipeline(InputRequest()) //Why is this of type Either[_, Output2]
  }
}
```

What am I missing? How can I get the return type to *not* be `Either[Any, Output2]` but rather the base/sealed trait? Is this possible to do generically?

Comment: Well, your `andThenE` discards the type of the **Left**... so not sure why you even ask why it does that, you told it to do it.

Comment: I see your point - but how can I get it to not do that? The output of `andThenE` always turns out to be `Either[_,C]` since the error can come from the *previous* function in the chain or this one and both can be of different types. I don't want to declare the *type* of the error in a generic function, hence the `andThenE` signature.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - updated the question to better reflect the source of the problem.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Could you please make your comment/link an answer so I may accept it? It does address my question and gets the compilation to succeed. I'll ask a new/follow-up question if something new comes up 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve the type of the **left** so we will modify the extension method to do that.

Note that, since both **eithers** can have different left types, what we will do is use a *type bound* to ask the compiler to infer the LUB between those types; thanks to `Any` this is always possibles *(although not always helpful)*.

```scala
object EitherExtension {
  implicit class AndThenEither[I, L1, R1](private val f: I => Either[L1, R1]) extends AnyVal {
    def andThenE[L2 >: L1, R2](g: R1 => Either[L2, R2]): I => Either[L2, R2] =
      i => f(i).flatMap(g)
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
import EitherExtension._

object AndThenComposition {
  sealed trait InternalError
  final case object Failure1 extends InternalError
  final case object Failure2 extends InternalError

  val function1: Int => Either[Failure1.type, String] = ???
  val function2: String  => Either[Failure2.type, Boolean] = ???

  def doSomething(input: Int): Either[InternalError, Boolean] = {
    (function1 andThenE function2)(input)
  }
}
```

---

*See the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/B0W1saFFR6iNnQxsMx63mA/2)*.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using this in production, and it's not just a learning thing, what you're looking for it's called Kleisli, and fortunately `cats-core` already implements it.

According to the cats-core [docs](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html):

> Kleisli enables composition of functions that return a monadic value,
> for instance an Option[Int] or a Either[String, List[Double]], without
> having functions take an Option or Either as a parameter, which can be
> strange and unwieldy.

Since Kleisli composes two functions with the signature `A => F[B]`, you'd need only one abstraction to be able to use Kleisli, which is creating a new type for your operation:

```scala
type Operation[A] = Either[InternalFailure, A]
```

By doing this, you should be able to use Kleisli like this:

```scala
import cats.data.Kleisli

val first: Kleisli[Operation, InputRequest, Output1] = Kleisli { request: InputRequest =>
  Left(Failure1())
}

val second: Kleisli[Operation, Output1, Output2] = Kleisli { output: Output1 =>
  Right(Output2())
}

val composed = first.andThen(second)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the `Kliesli` construct in `cats`.  One needn't import a library to get this going TBH. You've type aliased `Operation[A]` by forcing all `Either.Left` to be of type `InternalFailure`. I can do the same by fixing it in my `andThenE` too. This doesn't answer the question though and provides a solution by sidestepping my ask. Also, doing it this way or via `andThenE` are both "production viable" IMHO. It's relatively easy to create an abstract subclass of `Function1` and adding an `andThen` method to it and getting this done - I'm trying to do it via implicits instead.

Comment: I thought you were simply looking for a way to compose a function that returns a monad. Regarding your actual question, I don't think that's possible to do using flatMap only because `Either.flatMap` expects A1 (or Y, in your case) to be a supertype of `X`

Comment: That works with Scala 3 + Union types, though: https://gist.github.com/rodrigovedovato/fc7bacb8b15c8999c21982c208161c2e